# Microsoft Form Recognizer - Building a custom model that recognizes and extracts oval filled form responses

Tags: forms, azure-form-recognizer

Microsoft Form Recognizer - Need assistance with building a custom model that recognizes and extracts oval filled form responses. The form has a series of questions with five possible responses that are presented as fillable ovals horizontally displayed next each question. The first oval should be filled if the responder "Strongly Disagrees" (A), the second oval should be filled if he or she "Disagrees" (B), the third oval "Uncertain" (C), the fourth oval "Agrees" (D) and finally the fifth oval should be filled if he or she "Strongly Agrees" (E). Is it correct to draw a zone around and designate each fillable oval as a "selection mark" type, labeling and zoning each oval from left to right within the form as 1_A, 1_B, 1_C, 1_D and 1_E (five different recognition zones) for the first questions' five possible responses. 2_A, 2_B, 2_C, 2_D, 2_E (again, five different recognition zones) for second question's five possible responses and so on, including 3_A, 3_B, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Used the Layout pre-built model instead. Works like a charm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).